# Kendo Scheduler Custom view not refreshing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I created a Custom view for Kendo Scheduler to meet our project purpose. The problem is i cannot reload the view after filtering the resources .. scheduler.view("CustomDay");.. This code doesn't work.. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the custom view is the same as the name of the variable which contains the view.

```js
var CustomDay = kendo.ui.MultiDayView.extend({
   name: "CustomDay",
   ...
});
scheduler.view("CustomDay");
```

Answer (score 0):

scheduler.view("kendo.ui.DispatcherDayView");